# Internet Radio, node.js

Tags: node.js

I am trying to code a radio station for my friend. I would make him a web application where he can upload audio; either a group of tracks as a playlist, or a larger file, ie a guest dj set. The idea is that between guest sets the playlists fill the gaps.

I can figure out a que system, but what i need is the que to become a real-time stream, so if two users connected to the api they would hear the same thing, not trigger the start of the song.

I need it to be constantly playing, like a radio broad cast. im guessing node deployed (firebase) can manage this. looking into OBS but i dont want to have a computer switched on, i want this parked up in the cloud somewhere and my friend just keeps loading up the schedule, and it only falls silent if he uploads nothing or miss-manages his Q

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Probably know but you can take a look at [AzuraCast](https://github.com/AzuraCast/AzuraCast).